# Error while installing celery on ubuntu using 'pip install celery'

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, pip, celery

> OSError: [Errno:13] Permission Denied: 'usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

Comment: Considering using a virtualenv when pip installing a bunch of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sudo pip install celery` and enter your root password. It will work fine.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you mark the answer correct so that people don't answer any further and consider this as solved !